# Finding sum of top and bottom cards in shuffled deck

Tags: probability

The problem I am trying to solve is the following one: I have a pack of 10 cards with cards numbered from 1 to 6. The cards are shuffled and we need to find two things:

1) Find the probability that the number on the bottom card is larger than the number on the top card.

2) Letting $S$ be the random variable representing the sum of the numbers of the top and the bottom card. We need to find $P(S) = 4$

For the first part, I thought that the Probability space would be tuples where the first number represents the top card and the second number the bottom card, $(T,B)$ and so with this I found that the probability of the Bottom card being larger than the top card was $\frac{15}{36}$. However, the answers in my book say that it should be $0.5$. Can anyone explain why this is the case?

For the second problem, I thought that the possible tuples whose entries sum $4$ were $(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)$ and so the probability that the sum is 4 is $\frac{3}{36}$ but the answers say the final result should be $\frac{1}{45}$.

Comment: I don't believe the answer is $.5$, since ties are possible.  By symmetry, the answer should be $\frac 12\times (1-P_{tie})$ but you don't give us enough information to compute $P_{tie}$.

Comment: To be clear:  you say there are $10$ cards numbered $1$ to $6$.  That means there have to be duplicates, hence ties are possible, no?

Comment: Are the 10 cards chosen randomly from the 24 cards numbered 1,...,6?

Comment: @lulu I think there can be duplicates, that is a reason why I got confused with the answer from the book.

Comment: @krirkirk Why would there be 24 cards numberd 1 ... 6? The cards are like notes with numbers 1 through 6, there are no suits in this problem.

Comment: Well, we need to know how the cards are numbered.  It makes a big difference if they are $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4\}$ or $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,6\}$ say.

Comment: Note: if there was a typo and they meant to say there were six numbered $1$ to $6$ then $.5$ is the correct answer for the first part (since in this case $P_{tie}=0$) but for the second part we'd have $\frac 1{\binom 62}= \frac 1{15}$.

Comment: Alternate note:  if there was a typo and they meant to say that there were ten cards numbered from $1$ to $10$ then $.5$ is correct for the first part and for the second we get $\frac 1{\binom {10}2}=\frac 1{45}$ !!  So my guess is that this is what they intended.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

As written, there isn't enough information to solve the problem.  We'd need to know how, precisely, the ten cards were numbered.

We can reverse engineer the answers however, and find a variant which makes sense and which matches the given answers.

Variant:  suppose the ten cards were numbered from $1$ to $10$.

Note that with this choice, ties are not possible.

Problem $\#1$:  By symmetry, the probability that the first card exceeds the last is the same as the probability that the last exceeds the first.  Since ties are not possible the sum of the two must be $1$, so the probability is $\frac 12$.

Problem $\#2$:  There are exactly $\binom {10}2=45$ possibilities for the unordered choice of top and bottom.  These are equiprobable (again, ties are not possible).  Exactly one of these unordered pairs sums to $4$, namely $\{1,3\}$ so the desired probability is $\frac 1{45}$.